# (Only) set the logging level for RemoteLogHandler in GWT

Tags: gwt, logging, log4j

Can we set the logging level only for RemoteLogHandler?

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging" />
<set-property name='gwt.logging.enabled' value='TRUE' />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="**WARNING**"/>

<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
<set-property name='gwt.logging.popupHandler' value='ENABLED' />
```

// We want this, but it doesn't work:

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler.logLevel" value="**SEVERE**"/>
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution: ( which will not miss any logs, but it might catch one or two lower level logs )

```
        for (final java.util.logging.Handler h : Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers())
        {
            if (h instanceof com.google.gwt.logging.client.SimpleRemoteLogHandler)
            {
                ((com.google.gwt.logging.client.SimpleRemoteLogHandler) h).setLevel(logLevel);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do is inherit from `SimpleRemoteLogHandler` and override it's `isLoggable` method like to:

```
@Override
public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
  return super.isLoggable(record) && record.getLevel() == Level.SEVERE;
}
```

Then in the `.gwt.xml` file for your module you will set up for GWT to replace `SimpleRemoteLogHandler` with your own. This will work because GWT uses `GWT.create` to instantiate it.

```
<replace-with class="com.package.YourSimpleRemoteLogHandler">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.logging.client.SimpleRemoteLogHandler" />
    <any>
      <when-property-is name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
      <when-property-is name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />
    </any>
</replace-with>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `gwt.xml` configuration (leave the `gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler` property set to its default `DISABLED`), instantiate and add the `SimpleRemoteLogHandler` yourself:

```
SimpleRemoteLogHandler handler = new SimpleRemoteLogHandler();
handler.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(handler);

// Later...

Logger.getLogger("myLogger").log(Level.SEVERE, "A very important message.");
```